# How to split text file by id in python

Tags: python

I have a bunch of text files containing tab separated tables. The second column contains an id number, and each file is already sorted by that id number. I want to separate each file into multiple files by the id number in column 2. Here's what I have.

```
readpath = 'path-to-read-file'
writepath = 'path-to-write-file'
for filename in os.listdir(readpath):
     with open(readpath+filename, 'r') as fh:
          lines = fh.readlines()
     lastid = 0
     f = open(writepath+'checkme.txt', 'w')
     f.write(filename)
     for line in lines:
          thisid = line.split("\t")[1]
          if int(thisid) <> lastid:
               f.close()
               f = open(writepath+thisid+'-'+filename,'w')
               lastid = int(thisid)
          f.write(line)
     f.close()
```

What I get is simply a copy of all the read files with the first id number from each file in front of the new filenames. It is as if

```
thisid = line.split("\t")[1]
```

is only done once in the loop. Any clue to what is going on?

**EDIT**

The problem was my files used \r rather than \r\n to terminate lines. Corrected code (simply adding 'rU' when opening the read file and swapping != for <>):

```
readpath = 'path-to-read-file'
writepath = 'path-to-write-file'
for filename in os.listdir(readpath):
     with open(readpath+filename, 'rU') as fh:
          lines = fh.readlines()
     lastid = 0
     f = open(writepath+'checkme.txt', 'w')
     f.write(filename)
     for line in lines:
          thisid = line.split("\t")[1]
          if int(thisid) != lastid:
               f.close()
               f = open(writepath+thisid+'-'+filename,'w')
               lastid = int(thisid)
          f.write(line)
     f.close()
```

Comment: Have you checked what `int(thisid)` actually evaluates to on each pass round the loop, for example by adding a `print(int(thisid))` before the `if` block?

Comment: I just changed `f.write(line+'\r')` to `f.write(thisid+line+'\r')` the `thisid` only appears on the first line.

Comment: Just to note: `<>` was removed in Python 3.x and was deprecated even if 2.x - use `!=` instead

Comment: "the `thisid` only appears on the first line" sounds to me like the loop is only executing once, and the whole of the file is in `line`, so it was never split into separate lines when it was read in by `readlines()` - are the line terminators nonstandard in some way? How many elements does `lines` contain after the `readlines()`? This is basic debugging :-/

Comment: @nekomatic Thanks... you put me on the right track. The files I am trying to convert use `\r` to mark lines rather than `\r\n` that Python's readlines() expects. I simply specified `'rU'` when opening the files and readlines() recognized them with [universal newlines support](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)

Comment: "Is not equal to" is `!=` not `=!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're dealing with tab delimited files, then you can use the `csv` module, and take advantage of the fact that `itertools.groupby` will do the previous/current tracking of the id for you. Also utilise `os.path.join` to make sure your filenames end up joining correctly.

Untested:

```
import os
import csv
from itertools import groupby

readpath = 'path-to-read-file'
writepath = 'path-to-write-file'

for filename in os.listdir(readpath):
    with open(os.path.join(readpath, filename)) as fin:
        tabin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
        for file_id, rows in groupby(tabin, lambda L: L[1]):
            with open(os.path.join(writepath, file_id + '-' + filename), 'w') as fout:
                tabout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
                tabout.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Looks like the way to do it. Seems to be a problem somewhere though.

Comment: @Joseph if at some point you feel like sharing that - it'd probably be useful :p

Comment: Found the problem with my original code... The files I am trying to convert use `\r` to mark lines rather than `\r\n` that Python's readlines() expects. I simply specified `'rU'` when opening the files and readlines() recognized them with [universal newlines support](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)

Comment: I just tested your solution adding `, 'rU'` when opening the read file. Your solution works...only problem is it adds a blank line between each row. If it weren't for this (and it should be an easy fix), I'd like your code better.

Comment: @Joseph sadly `csv.reader` always ignores the `lineterminator` option - you could try opening the output  file in `wb` mode though - that should alleviate the blank rows

Comment: @Joseph and again, to note: don't forget to change `<>` to `!=` - you'll find deprecation warnings/linter errors or a complete fail in Python 3

Comment: Did that...basic habits are hard to break :-)